# manage Multiple back stacks when using bottom navigation and navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I am using bottom navigation and I have 3 main fragment in it (fragment 1, 2 and 3 in image) and there is some other fragments that I manage them in navigation component so they are not in bottom navigation menu.
there are some directions between all fragments (you can see in image)

[image: navigation.xml]

How should I manage this Directions with bottom navigation?